Putnam 1987 Algebra Question
I've been trying to solve the Putnam 1987 A1 question:
A$-$1 $\quad$ Curves $A,B,C$ and $D$ are defined in the plane as follows:
\begin{equation*}
 A=\left\{(x,y):x^2-y^2=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right\}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 B=\left\{(x,y):2xy+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=3\right\}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 C=\left\{(x,y):x^3-3xy^2+3y=1\right\}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 D=\left\{(x,y):3x^2y-3x-y^3=0\right\}
\end{equation*}
Prove that $A\cap B=C\cap D$
By doing some algebra, I showed that considering $A$ and $B$ you can show that it leads to $C$ being true and then $D$ being true, and by showing that $C,D$ show $A,B$ the proof is complete.
My question is, when doing the problem I was expecting that by playing around with $A$ and $B$ I would get $C$ and $D$ already "mixed", or some version where both equations were combined. It is strange to me that by playing around with $A$ and $B$ it is possible to get $C$ and $D$ separately. The points that $A\cap B$ define are not lines or curves but just singular points, but why would $A,B$ give me $C$ for example separate from $D$? Couldn't someone make the mistake that because one could get to $C$ from $A$ and $B$, then all the points in $C$ belong to $A\cap B$, when this is not the case? It's just strange to me that the equations $C$ and $D$ can come out separately from $A,B$ rather than already in some combined form.

"By doing some algebra, I showed that" : please edit your posting to show your work in a very clear fashion, and please express the conclusions proven by your work in a very clear fashion.

This boils down to whether your manipulations are reversible. If you're combining two equations to get a third equation, it's likely that you're proving a statement of the form $P\land Q\implies R$, not the form $P\land Q\iff R$. Think about the logic behind your steps. ("If we assume $(x,y)$ satisfies both $P$ and $Q$, then we can conclude that $(x,y)$ satisfies $R$...")
